# OSX terminal rm -rf files from a symbolic link

Tags: macos, terminal

Running OSX 10.11.2, I need to rm -rf the file in the location indicated in the symbolic links below for atom, npm and node as well as the links. I am currently log in as a user but terminal is in su mode.
I tried few commands for no avail. I tried to go to those locations but do not know how to.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: You can use `readlink` to get the target path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, [`rm`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/rm.1.html) itself does not have a suitable option to remove the files that the links point to.  That would make it cumbersome to do this in a single command.  A script helps:

```
#!/bin/sh
for name in "$@"
do
    if [ -L "$name" ]
    then
        target=$(stat -f '%Y' "$name")
        $0 "$target"
    fi
    [ -e "$name" ] && rm -rf "$name"
done
```

The script uses the OSX [`stat`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/readlink.1.html) command to obtain the link target, and recurs to itself, to remove the target (which could be another link), and after removing the target, removes the link (or non-link, as the case may be).

In a comment, OP clarified that the link itself should not be removed.  That can be done by changing the test:

```
#!/bin/sh
for name in "$@"
do
    if [ -L "$name" ]
    then
        target=$(stat -f '%Y' "$name")
        $0 "$target"
    fi
    [ -e "$name" ] && [ ! -L "$name" ] && rm -rf "$name"
done
```

Comment: I need to leave the app symlink alone and not touch it, as well as other symlink which have been created since my post. I do not see where in your code an exception is made to exclude such,  thx

Comment: Thomas: Thanks for updating your answer. My comments relate to selecting a certain listing for example in the image I posted, say I want to ignore the apm line. Sorry apm was spell corrected by the browser to app which was not my intension. It would be better to modify your code to select the item to be deleted as well as selected the item(s) to be excluded.